# Universal cycles for $k$-sets of an $n$-set

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics

Let $[n] = \{1, \ldots, n \}$, and let $S(n,k)$ be the family of $k$-element subsets of $[n]$.

A cyclic word $w$ over alphabet $[n]$ is called a *universal cycle for* $S(n,k)$ if each element of $S(n,k)$ appears in $w$ as a factor (continuous subword) **exatly once**.

---

**Examlpe**

$n=8$, $k=3$

$w = 02456145712361246703671345034601250135672560234723570147$.

Here, for example, since the first 3-letter subword $024$ represents the 3-set $\{ 0,2,4 \}$ then none of the five other 3-letter subwords $042$, $204$, $240$, $402$ and $420$ can occur in $w$.

---

It is not hard to see that if $S(n,k)$ has a universal cycle, then $k$ divides $\binom{n-1}{k-1}$.

The following conjecture was proposed in [*Chung F., Diaconis P., Graham R. Universal cycles for combinatorial structures // Discrete Mathematics (1992)*]

**Conjecture**. For every natural $k$ there is $n_0(k)$ such that a universal cycle for $S(n,k)$ always exists provided that $k$ divides $\binom{n-1}{k-1}$ and $n \geq n_0(k)$.

I'm wondering if this conjecture is still open, and if yes, then what would be a good reference to check recent progress?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the conjecture is still open. See the comment on Problem 476 and references therein for partial results in the paper below.

> Jackson, Brad; Stevens, Brett; Hurlbert, Glenn. [Research problems on Gray codes and universal cycles.](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/6844/94b7d88c34caf8c9e611cb3f73c1992b3543.pdf?_ga=2.227170527.331965502.1499628766-960685506.1499628766) Discrete Math. 309 (2009), no. 17, 5341--5348.

This is fairly recent (2009). A look at the papers which cite the above shows the following paper with some further results.

> Blanca, Antonio; Godbole, Anant P. [On universal cycles for new classes of combinatorial structures.](https://arxiv.org/abs/1008.2251) SIAM J. Discrete Math. 25 (2011), no. 4, 1832--1842.